# Importing a pipe in 2 different modules

Tags: angular

I have 2 components where I need to use the same pipe, and my app has 3 modules.

1. AppModule
2. ProjectModule -> inside AppModule
3. OverviewModule -> inside ProjectModule

I need to use my pipe in a component located at my ProjectModule and in a compoent located in my OverviewModule. I tried to import the pipe in my AppModule, but then I get:

```
The pipe 'keys' could not be found
```

When I tried to import it in my ProjectModule and in my Overview module seperately, and I got the following error:

> KeysPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: OverviewModule and
>   ProjectModule! Please consider moving KeysPipe to a higher module that
>   imports OverviewModule and BusinessModule. You can also create a new
>   NgModule that exports and includes KeysPipe then import that NgModule
>   in OverviewModule and ProjectModule.

I couldn't figure out what to do in order to make the pipe work in both of my modules. I already tried to place it in my app module.. any Ideas?

Comment: You need to import the module that contains the pipe instead of the pipe. The pipe like other directives, and components, can only be listed in `declarations` of exactly one `@NgModule()`

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, please let me know if I understood correctly, in order to import this pipe in my case I'll have to import the whole module contains it? If yes, I would perfer to create the same pipe twice and import the pipe instead of importing the whole module. Isn't it a better solution?

Comment: It's definitely not a better solution. As your app will grow you'll have several components, directives, and pipes you want to use together. Put these in a shared module and import the module to make them all available to the current module at once. Duplicate pipes will be confusing. When you fix a bug or add a feature and wonder why it's not working - just to find out you changed the wrong one ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but it seem like there is still an issue. I created a `SharedModule` and import the KeysPipe in it's `declrations[]`. I imported this `SharedModule` in the `imports[]` of the modules where I need to use this pipe, and I get `parse errors:
The pipe 'keys' could not be found`.

Comment: You need to add the pipe to `exports: []` as well in `ShardModule` to make it available to importing modules.